# Regex check if a file has any extension

Tags: regex, path, file-extension

I am looking for a regex to test if a file has any extension. I define it as: **file has an extension if there is no slashes present after the last "."**. The slashes are always backslashes.

I started with this regex

```
.*\..*[^\\]
```

Which translates to

```
.*          Any char, any number of repetitions 
\.          Literal .
.*          Any char, any number of repetitions 
[^\\]       Any char that is NOT in a class of [single slash]
```

This is my test data (excluding ##, which is my comments)

```
\path\foo.txt            ## I only want to capture this line
\pa.th\foo               ## But my regex also captures this line <-- PROBLEM HERE
\path\foo                ## This line is correctly filtered out
```

What would be a regex to do this?

Comment: You'll need a negative lookahead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct. Use this:

```
^.*\.[^\\]+$
```

[Sample](http://rubular.com/r/bBeB2deWlx) at rubular.

Comment: @C.B. no, that's why I surrounded everything between ^$

Comment: @oleksii it might be related to single/multiline mode of the regex

Comment: @oleksii: if you want to use each line as a separate test, you need to add the multiline `m` flag so that `^$` match the beginning and end of a line and not of the whole string.

Comment: @The regex that I finally used was `^.*\.[^\\$]`. I used it in C# regexp class inside NEsper. Marking this as correct. As the difference is only minor and the sample link online worked fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @oleksii - Your final solution (from previous comment): `^.*\.[^\\$]` makes no sense and does not meet the requirements of your question. e.g. the valid filename: `file.$$$` does NOT match and the invalid filename: `\pa.th\foo` DOES match. However, the answer provided by BlackBear here, _does_ work correctly. That said, the pattern I'd recommend is just: `\.[^.\\]+$`, which matches just the extension part of a filename (i.e. the last dot followed by one or more non-dot, non-backslashes followed by the end of string).

Comment: @ridgerunner That's right. I looked at the `^.*\.[^\\$]` and this bit `[^\\$]` doesn't make sense indeed. I think my problem was in the line ending (char returns). Once I made a line by line match then both your solution `\.[^.\\]+$` and the suggested solution `^.*\.[^\\]+$` worked fine. Thank you.

Comment: Just a word of warning: `^.*\.[^\\$]` would match any file or folder starting with a dot which are quite common. The directory `.git` and the files`.ssh` and `.bashrc` would all be matches. None of these can be accurately described as a "file" that "has an extension."

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use a regular expression here. I'd `split` on `/` and `.`.

```
var path = '\some\path\foo\bar.htm',
    hasExtension = path.split('\').pop().split('.').length > 1;

if (hasExtension) console.log('Weee!');
```

Here goes a more simple function to check it.

```
const hasExtension = path => {
    const lastDotIndex = path.lastIndexOf('.')
    return lastDotIndex > 1 && path.length - 1 > lastDotIndex
}

if (hasExtension(path)) console.log('Sweet')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try even more simpler approach:

```
(\.[^\\]+)$
```

**Details:**

```
$      = Look from the end of string
[^\\]+ = Any character except path separator one or more time
\.     = looks for <dot> character before extension
```

#### [Live Demo](http://rubular.com/r/fpCvh4qKxG)

Comment: For those using Elasticsearch, you need to add some escapes. `(./[^\\/]+)$`